# (ASP Classic) default date format reverted mysteriously

Tags: .net, asp-classic, date-format, globalization, windows-server-2016

The business I work for is running an ASP Classic website (i know..) on a fresh install of Windows Server 2016.  Everything was previously fine on a 2012 server, however our hosts told us there was a catastrophic HDD failure and they basically had to wipe everything and give us a fresh OS, so I've been attempting to rebuild the entire thing.

Everything works, but dates in the ASP Classic web pages are defaulting to US format with no leading zeroes - for example if I retrieve a YYYYMMDD date from the SQL Server database, it will correctly identify the month/day but simply default to display it in US format.  If I use our code to reformat it by using `month(dateVar)` and `day(dateVar)` everything still works

Here's what I've done to try and fix it, mostly stuff I found on stack overflow:

- set .NET Globalization to en-GB (culture and ui-culture)
- checked and made sure there are no group policies applied
- changed Windows regional and date format settings via the OS
- changed 'sShortDate' and 'sLongDate' format in registry `HKEY_USERS/HKEY_LOCAL_USERS -> .DEFAULT -> Control Panel -> International`
- added vbscript locale identifier `LCID=2057` to test in one ASP page, and also in a Global.asa file to no avail

Last night at 11pm it was all working beautifully.  This morning I awoke to find emails saying that the date formats are wrong again.  As far as I can tell, the server has been up the entire time too

I've checked and re-checked everything I already changed, and it's all exactly how I left it... but the date format has gone from (for example) 21/01/2018 to 1/21/2018

is there something I'm missing?  I'm not that familiar with Windows Server

Comment: `<%@  LCID="2057" %>` has always worked for me.  I take it you are putting it in the declaration at the start of the page

Comment: ah, I didn't realise you required the @ symbol - this works but only for the page it's in.  I could manually go and add this to every file but that would be extremely laborious - is there some way to apply it globally?  I tried adding it to our serverSettings.inc file but this produced an error (The @ command can only be used once within the Active Server Page)

Comment: If it's too much effort to use the procesing directive (the bit with the @ symbol) you could try setting it as a session variable. `Session.LCID=2057`.  Global.asa would be the obvious place but if you have an include file which every page uses it should work there too.

Comment: thanks John you're a life safer - I've set up a Global.asa file and it's now working!

Comment: @RossCampbell You can also set the default LCID in the ASP section in the IIS Manager for the Website. Also changing regional settings should work without having to specify LCID at all, likelihood is you changed the setting for the logged in user not for the whole server, the process to setting a default language in Windows 10 based OSs like Windows Server 2016 is very flakey.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, thanks to John.

I created a `Global.asa` file in the root directory of the site and added:

`<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
  sub Session_OnStart
    Session.LCID="2057" 'UK
  end sub
</script>`

This then resolved the issue - which can be tested with ASP `Response.write getLocale`

I had two sites that are added as Applications in IIS, and I had to copy `Global.asa` into their folders also

> <%@ LCID="2057" %> has always worked for me. I take it you are putting it in the declaration at the start of the page
>
> If it's too much effort to use the procesing directive (the bit with the @ symbol) you could try setting it as a session variable. Session.LCID=2057. Global.asa would be the obvious place but if you have an include file which every page uses it should work there too